# Unmarshalling table-like JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, elasticsearch, unmarshalling

ElasticSearch returns results in a table-like structure in JSON (column descriptions, then records as arrays). Example:

```
{
  "columns" : [
    {
      "name" : "a",
      "type" : "text"
    },
    {
      "name" : "b",
      "type" : "text"
    }
  ],
  "rows" : [
    [
      "a1",
      "b1"
    ],
    [
      "a2",
      "b2"
    ]
  ],
  "cursor" : "Qmd9STC/hM/p3fEF9F7D7FehVn+yLHX4SGVcAB7vk9kGwLjZ4wgfQex4gH+9PuSRmweeHMKtkFiUbTRNFC9bbse4zszAaMv9zKG11aEXQzJzjlRuypdHyDA+RPz66xPVuI1UUkoFpw5EY7k8bFKQ31zhn7x0ie0gv4jGseJJetzXNugw8TwYNR6Id0MVSihm0ogRH9WNFA72CJnqoa26zDPIgXSm/D6QPP40/yXozyAE0gzMnFUYynZf1vlCVdHTQPrCo0TrSMlHvx3BPza5ZnzyLEYZLKULRrTUvtiMOxj+5Ru4izLWSB0jLqeTEkbl5OK9Tyniuq45PeZmZ39UBQ=="
}
```

Is there a best practice to unmarshal this into an array of Go structs (structs with meaningful field names). E.g.:

```
type Platipus struct {
    A string
    B string
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

const s = `
{
   "rows" : [
      ["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"]
   ]
}
`

type platipus struct { A, B string }

func (p *platipus) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
   a := []*string{&p.A, &p.B}
   return json.Unmarshal(b, &a)
}

func main() {
   var p struct {
      Rows []platipus
   }
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &p)
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p.Rows) // [{A:a1 B:b1} {A:a2 B:b2}]
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json#RawMessage.UnmarshalJSON